# Passing data into a vertex shader for perspective divide

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

In OpenGL and GLSL, I am just learning about perspective projection and the vertex shader. However, I am a little confused about what data actually needs to be passed to the vertex shader, and what needs to be done in the shader code itself.

I have two questions:

1. Suppose I have a triangle defined in 3D coordinates (x,y,z). Do I need to pass a 4D vector with values (x,y,z,w), where w = z? Or do I just pass the 3D vector? The reason I ask is that I know that somewhere in the pipeline, the x and y coordinates are divided by the w component, in the perspective divide.
2. In the vertex shader code, do I need to manually divide the x and y components by the w component myself? Or is this taken care of automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The OpenGL implementation does the perspective divide in between the vertex and fragment shaders.

You can input whatever you want into a vertex shader; the perspective divide happens after the vertex shader on the `gl_Position` variable which is a `vec4`.

(I don't know how tessellation shaders fit into this)

Comment: The perspective divide is done in the `vertex post-processing stage` that is after vertex shader, tesselation and geometry shader. See here https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview#Vertex_post-processing

Answer (score 0):

as we know, there are 6 `space`s in OpenGL:

`model/object space`--homogeneous model coordinates: (x,y,z,1) in true units

```
         `model-world transform`
```

`world space`--world coordinates: (x,y,z,1) in true units

```
         `world-view transform`
```

`view/camera/eye space`--eye coordinates: (x,y,z,1) in true units

```
         `perspective projection`/`orthographic projection`
```

`clip space`--homogeneous clip coordinates: (x,y,z,w) `OpenGL true input`

```
         `projective division`
```

`NDC space`--normalized device coordinates---x->(-1,1)、y->(-1,1)、z->(0,1)

`window space`--window coordinates:(x,y) in pixels、depth coordinates:z->(0,1)

So the answer is:

Q1: `perspective projection` automatically converts (x,y,z,1) to (x,y,z,w).

Q2: no, you don't. anything after `OpenGL true input` can be automatically done by OpenGL and you can not control it in vertex shader.